# Using Process Builder to Create a Task

Tags: process-builder

I have no experience with process builder or writing formulas.  I have been struggling to create a task that will remind the opportunity owner to contact the account associated with the opportunity, 365 days after the opportunity moves into the Business Won stage.

In the process builder, I set up the trigger (an opportunity is created) and defined a criteria with the first condition being:

- Field: Opportunity Stage Name
- Operator:  Equals
- Type: Picklist
- Value:  Business Won

I am trying to set a second condition to represent the amount of time that has passed.  I want to only take the action of setting a follow-up task if the Opportunity Close Date is more than 365 days old.    I attempted to set the condition as:

- Field: Opportunity Close Date
- Operator: Greater than
- List item: Formula
- Value:  ?????

I know it needs to be Today's date - 365 but I don't know how to write it.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: If you are new to Salesforce, a good place to start is [Salesforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails) for tutorials on many subjects, and also check the Salesforce and Dreamforce channels on Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using **Time-Based Workflow** to create the `Task`.  Typically I would avoid workflow for field updates but this is Task creation so this could be solved either by process builder, or workflow.  Can you accept using workflow time-based action or must it be process builder? A workflow alternative is below:

**Evaluation Criteria** could be "`Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria`"

**Rule Criteria** could be `Opportunity: Won EQUALS True`.

**Time-based workflows** can be monitored by system admins in the Setup Menu, and the docs describe how items in the queue enter/leave etc.

If you solve this using **Time-based Workflow** you'll probably want to read at least the docs below.  As of January 2021 there are some relevant phrases in those docs to consider:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&type=5
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_queue.htm&type=5

relevant phrases from those docs (as of January 2021):

- "Evaluation Criteria"
- "subsequently meet criteria"
- "If the evaluation criteria is set to Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, the workflow rule evaluates its time triggers only once"
- "Deleting a record that has pending actions removes the pending
  actions from the workflow queue"
- "removed from the queue"

Here is an example:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.  I think this could work.  I didn't know how workflows work, so did not consider it.   I am going to dig into this today and I'll let you know if I am successful.  I appreciate the time you took to detail this out.